# regular expression to find only dot(.) followed by two decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

if i have a number string (input 26.202.09), I want to find and replace the dot that is followed by more than two numbers to comma (,)(output 26,202.09)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following pattern:

```
/\.(\d{3,})/
```

Which will match 3 or more (`{3,}`) digits (`\d`) followed after a period (`\.`), and will group the digits so that they can be referenced in the replacement string using `$1` like so:

```js
const str = '26.202.09';
const res = str.replace(/\.(\d{3,})/g, ',$1');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a postcondition:
`\.(?=\d{3,})`
will match a dot followed by three or more numbers but does not count the numbers in the match